# WebpackDevserve works only at the rootUrl of the site

Tags: angularjs, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4, ngroute

I have a test site where I test
Webpack in conjunction with AngularJS. Everything was fine until I started learning the routing.

Here is my webpack-config

```
'use strict';
const webpack = require('webpack');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');



const minimizerBlock = {
    minimizer: [
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
            uglifyOptions: {
                warnings: false,
                parse: {},
                compress: {},
                mangle: true,
                output: null,
                toplevel: false,
                nameCache: null,
                ie8: false,
                keep_fnames: false,
            },
        }),
        new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
    ]
}

const config = {
    entry: { main: './frontend/src/index.js' },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public'),
        filename: 'main.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        port: 80,
        overlay: true,
        proxy: {
            '*': 'http://localhost:8888'
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, use: { loader: "babel-loader" } },
            { test: /\.less$/, use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "less-loader"] },
            { test: /\.scss$/, use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"] },
            { test: /\.sass$/, use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"] },
            { test: /(\.css$)/, loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif|webp)$/,
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, './frontend/image/')
                ],
                use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[path][name].[ext]',
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, './frontend/fonts/')
                ],
                use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[path][name].[ext]',
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(mp3)$/,
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, './frontend/audio/')
                ],
                use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[path][name].[ext]',
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(html)$/,
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, './frontend/pages/')
                ],
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[path][name].[ext]',
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'extract-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'html-loader',
                        options: {
                            interpolate: true,
                        }
                    }
                ],
                exclude: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend/src/', 'template.html')
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: './index.css',
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend/src/', 'template.html'),
            filename: 'index.html',
            inject: true,
            favicon: 'frontend/image/icons/iconfinder_tech_0001_4023871.png'
        })

    ]
};
module.exports = (env, options) => {
    let production = options.mode == 'production';
    config.devtool = production ? false : 'inline-cheap-module-source-map';
    config.optimization = production ? minimizerBlock : {};
    return config;
}
```

Everything works as I wanted, but after I made changes to the code, or rather I wrote the AngularJs routing config for a site that works great.

```
import app from '../module/main-module.js';
import importFiles from '../getFiles.js';



app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: importFiles.pages[3],
            })
            .when('/my-works', {
                templateUrl: importFiles.pages[4],
            })
            .when('/interesting-topics', {
                templateUrl: importFiles.pages[2],
            })
            .when('/about-me', {
                templateUrl: importFiles.pages[0],
            })
            .when('/contact-me', {
                templateUrl: importFiles.pages[1],
            }).otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/',
            });
            $locationProvider.html5Mode({
              enabled: true,
              requireBase: false
        });
    }]);
```

While I'm in the root ***page http://localhost*** page everything works as it should.

As soon as I start to click on the links, everything is ok too, the problems start when I am not at the root of the site and reload the page. I have lost all content.

This is how the site looks like before reloading the page.

[image]

This is how the site looks like after reloading the page.

[image]

I only have this problem if the site is launched in development mode, when the public folder is missing, if you start it in production mode, then the public folder is created and this is not a problem.

Even if I do not delete the public folder and run the project in development mode, the problem is also missing.

How do I properly configure to correct the error?

My opinion is that I have not correctly configured webDevServer. But I couldn’t figure it out myself, although I’ve been studying AngularJs for two weeks and I don’t understand it very well, there may be a problem with the ngRoute configuration

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, the reason for this behavior was the config, but rather the settings in it

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: false,
  requireBase: false
});
```

I tried to clear the line from `#`

`http://localhost/#!/interesting-topics`

`http://localhost/interesting-topics`

And now I do not know how to set it up so that there is no problem described above in the question and there is a path without `#`